Fatal exception java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError with MarketingCloudSdk 8.1.5 for Android
I recently upgraded and Android app to

compileSdk 34

and updated MarketingCloudSdk to 8.1.5
For some phones (eg. Galaxy Note 10) I have this exception at start up:
          Fatal Exception: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found class com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderClient, but interface was expected (declaration of 'com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderClient' appears in base.apk!classes3.dex)
   at com.salesforce.marketingcloud.location.d.e(:46)
   at com.salesforce.marketingcloud.location.h.a(SourceFile:5)
   at com.salesforce.marketingcloud.messages.d.c(SourceFile:2)
   at com.salesforce.marketingcloud.messages.d.c(SourceFile:1)
   at com.salesforce.marketingcloud.messages.d.a(SourceFile:4)
   at com.salesforce.marketingcloud.messages.d.init(:1)
   at com.salesforce.marketingcloud.MarketingCloudSdk.a(SourceFile:4)
   at com.salesforce.marketingcloud.MarketingCloudSdk.a(SourceFile:2)
   at com.salesforce.marketingcloud.MarketingCloudSdk$a.run(:37)
   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:920)
    

How can i solve this?
Thanks
Alberto

Was this issue resolved. I am facing the same error now. Please respond.

No news mate, still facing the same issue
